# What is the way for display loading with ajax sync call in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Is there any way to display loading in chrome when using async:false in ajax call.
With settimeout there is many problems when using more than one ajax sync call within settimeout funcion.
And loading works well without settimeout in firefox but not working in chrome.

Please suggest any other way to display loading.

Code:

```
 function setDetails() {
            debugger;
            jQuery('loading').show();
            ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');

           setTimeout(function () {

            var serverUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
            var oDataUri = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_pasm_tblSet";
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                url: oDataUri,
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                    debugger;
                    var isDomainExists = false;
                    if (data == null || data.d.results.length <= 0 ) {
                        debugger;
                        //other code
                        oDataUri1 = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_pasm_tblSet";
                        debugger;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            datatype: "json",
                            url: oDataUri1,
                            data: jsonPO,
                            async: false,
                            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            },
                            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                                debugger;
                                checkInCRM();
                                ajaxindicatorstop();
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("Error while store license data: " + errorThrown);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else {
                        if (keyDetail != data.d.results[0].new_var)
                        {
                            oDataUri1 = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_pasm_tblSet(guid'" + id + "')";
                            debugger;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                datatype: "json",
                                url: oDataUri1,
                                data: jsonPO,
                                async: false,
                                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
                                },
                                success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

                                    checkInCRM();
                                    ajaxindicatorstop();
                                },
                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert("Error while store license data: " + errorThrown);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {}
                    }
                    ajaxindicatorstop();
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error while getting license data: " + errorThrown);
                    onclickflag = false;
                }
            });
            ajaxindicatorstop();
            }, 10);
        }

function ajaxindicatorstart(text) {
            if (jQuery('body').find('#resultLoading').attr('id') != 'resultLoading') {
                jQuery('body').append('<div id="resultLoading" style="display:none"><div><img src="new_loading.gif"><div>' + text + '</div></div><div class="bg"></div></div>');
            }
            //
            jQuery('#resultLoading').css({
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'z-index': '10000000',
                'top': '0',
                'left': '0',
                'right': '0',
                'bottom': '0',
                'margin': 'auto'
            });

            jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').css({
                'background': '#000000',
                'opacity': '0.7',
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': '0'
            });

            jQuery('#resultLoading>div:first').css({
                'width': '250px',
                'height': '75px',
                'text-align': 'center',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0',
                'left': '0',
                'right': '0',
                'bottom': '0',
                'margin': 'auto',
                'font-size': '16px',
                'z-index': '10',
                'color': '#ffffff'

            });

            jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
            jQuery('#resultLoading').fadeIn(300);
            jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
        }
        function ajaxindicatorstop() {
            jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
            jQuery('#resultLoading').fadeOut(300);
            jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'default');
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code that is failing to work for you in chrome.

Comment: How about not doing synchronous Ajax?

Comment: i think you don't know the difference between synchronous  and asynchronous calls

Comment: Here you go – https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8819

Comment: @madalinivascu I am beginner. However, I have tried my best from google. If I would know everything, I wouldn't need to contact you or the community

Comment: @nnnnnn I want sync call only

Comment: @jedifans I put my Code.and after completion of ajax call just for 2 sec loading is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

@Haresh Vidja answer code is perfect.... Only issue is that the loader image / div does not auto display inside `beforeSend`.
Below is the solution:

```
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#resultLoading').show();
            ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');
            //XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
```

In `beforeSend`when `ajax` request is sent, the loader loads till the time the time success is reached & `ajaxindicatorstop()` is triggered in success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery there is many ways to display loader when ajax start and ajax complete event.

**Only for Perticular Request**

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
      // write code for show loader here
   },
   complete: function(xhr, status){
      // write code for show loader here
   }

});
```

**If you want to set Globally for each ajax request**

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
// write code for show loader here
});
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
// write code for hide loader here
});
```

**Corrections in your Code**

```
function setDetails() {
    jQuery('loading').show();

    var serverUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
    var oDataUri = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_pasm_tblSet";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: oDataUri,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {

            ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');

            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            debugger;
            var isDomainExists = false;
            if (data == null || data.d.results.length <= 0 ) {
                debugger;
                //other code
                oDataUri1 = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_pasm_tblSet";
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    url: oDataUri1,
                    data: jsonPO,
                    async: false,
                    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                        debugger;
                        checkInCRM();
                        ajaxindicatorstop();
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error while store license data: " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                if (keyDetail != data.d.results[0].new_var)
                {
                    oDataUri1 = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_pasm_tblSet(guid'" + id + "')";
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "json",
                        url: oDataUri1,
                        data: jsonPO,
                        async: false,
                        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
                        },
                        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                            checkInCRM();
                            ajaxindicatorstop();
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error while store license data: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {}
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error while getting license data: " + errorThrown);
            onclickflag = false;
        }
        complete: function(){
            ajaxindicatorstop();
        }
    });
}
function ajaxindicatorstart(text) {
    if (jQuery('body').find('#resultLoading').attr('id') != 'resultLoading') {
        jQuery('body').append('<div id="resultLoading" style="display:none"><div><img src="new_loading.gif"><div>' + text + '</div></div><div class="bg"></div></div>');
    }
    //
    jQuery('#resultLoading').css({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        'position': 'fixed',
        'z-index': '10000000',
        'top': '0',
        'left': '0',
        'right': '0',
        'bottom': '0',
        'margin': 'auto'
    });
    jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').css({
        'background': '#000000',
        'opacity': '0.7',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '0'
    });
    jQuery('#resultLoading>div:first').css({
        'width': '250px',
        'height': '75px',
        'text-align': 'center',
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0',
        'left': '0',
        'right': '0',
        'bottom': '0',
        'margin': 'auto',
        'font-size': '16px',
        'z-index': '10',
        'color': '#ffffff'
    });
    jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
    jQuery('#resultLoading').fadeIn(300);
    jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
}
function ajaxindicatorstop() {
    jQuery('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
    jQuery('#resultLoading').fadeOut(300);
    jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'default');
}
```

Comment: Hi Haresh, I tried by put show loading in beforesend but not worked.

Comment: Hi Chhaya thanks for your feedback, can you put your HTML and JS code in your description?

Comment: In your code you have also called `ajaxindicatorstart()` funcction before ajax function so it should be worked.

Comment: As output of this code ,after completion of ajax call just for 2 second loading is displayed.

Comment: I have made come corrections in your code.. please check my answer

Comment: Sorry, I cant help more... you have to debug your code manually because all code you have .. if you like my answer then up vote.. if you feel this answer helps you then mark as correct.

Comment: ohk... can you try with async: true? :)

Comment: did you get succes on it?

Comment: Yes. I got success.

Comment: Can I know how you got success?

Comment: That I wrote in post.

Comment: Ok, whatever.. but great that you got success... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thnx all for the help.And Finally I got the answer.

With adding `jQuery('loading').show();` in beforesend also and by settimeout to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. and got this solution

Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

if you are using Property "async: false" in ajax call then please try this solution.

```
    $("div.spanner").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveAnswer")',
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result.Status) {                            
                        bool = true;

                    } else {
                        alert(result.Message);
                    }
                },
            error: function (result) {
                $("div.spanner").hide();
                }
        });
    }, 10);
```